# Timeout does not work in AngularJS Karma - Jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My code:

```
describe('Popup', function(){

it("Should close on second click", function(){
        compileDirective(400,'click','true');  
            element.triggerHandler('click');
            timeout(function() {
                 element.triggerHandler('click');
                 scope.$digest();
                 timeout.flush();
                 element.remove();
                 $(".sidepopright").remove();
             }, 1000);

        });

});
```

I want to make a delay for the second click of the popup, so I put a timeout after the first click. However, it does not work. Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the injectable service [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), not timeout.

```
$timeout(function () {
// Do something
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I have define timeout = $timeout in beforeEach() section, so, it is not the $timeout problem..any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $timeout.flush(); to simulate the timeout completion in your unit test.